# Get push notification payload when opening app, Android Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, push, appcelerator

I have activated push notifications in my application and I have done all the settings with Google and Apple to be able to send from the Appcelerator Dashboard.
I can receive notifications on both Android and iOS without any problems.
In iOS, when i click the notification from the notification center, the application opens and the callback function of Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications is executed automatically.
 The problem is that in Android, the function assigned to the callback event of the cloudPush module is not executed, I understand that it will be because when opening the application the listener is not yet created.
 If I receive the notification when the application is open the callback function runs smoothly.
 Reading in documentation of Android seems to me to understand that the notification is included in the extras of the intent when opening the application, but I am not clear what extra is, since in Appcelerator I do not find any function to obtain all the extras.
 Someone could give me an idea of ​​how to get the payload, whether or not when I click the notification the app is in the background, as if it is totally closed?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you telling that the Android App does not execue the callback when you click the notification and the app is closed ?

Comment: Yes, i push on the notification and the app open but the callback don't run